# How to get data from a form of an Html page to another page after clicking submit button, without going through the Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a form in Html and I want to return the data entered by the user on another page of an Html. I don't want to go through the client-server coding. Just a simple Html page with the data after clicking Submit button.
I am new to Html so just learning as you can see I have written an Html file name in the action attribute of the form. This is not working. Kindly reply, I cannot find the answer anywhere else.
I am open to javascript.

```
<form action="formData.html" method="POST">

<table width="70%"  cellpadding="8"> 
 <tr>      
     <td width="40%">First Name:</td>         
     <td> <input type="text" name="first_name" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>Middle Name:</td> 
     <td><input type="text" name="middle_name" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>Last Name:</td>
     <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="last_name" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>    
     <td>Gender :</td>
     <td width="30%"><input type="radio" name="gender" />Male</td>
     <td width="50%"><input type="radio" name="gender" />Female</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <input type="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>
```

Comment: The page where the data I want to be returned should be an HTML page.

Comment: is the other html page on the same domain @manish

Comment: Yes, the other page is in the same folder within same Project.-@JFit

Comment: so when you hit submit, it goes to 2nd page? and you want the inputs available for use on the other page? @manish

Comment: Yes, @JFit it goes to the 2nd Html page where I want. But the Input data is not displaying on the page. If you have an ans. kindly reply

Comment: Yes there are a number of ways to persist data between pages.. The easiest I reckon is probally Querystrings. so on the submit of the button you'd be calling the url of the 2nd page and supplying the values at the end like window.location = "/secondpage?value1=a&value2=b"

Answer (score 0):

You can try to save it in the url (e.g. http://example.com/sendto.html?abc=sb&def=sth) and then use js to read it, etc.

A code that is needed to get the variable is this :

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

@Copyright [jolly.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1045296/jolly-exe) from question [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Codepen Example : http://codepen.io/jamiechoi/pen/tmphb?foo=sometext

Comment: Yea, @Jamie  I can return the data in the url of another Html file through GET method. But I don't know how to retrieve it on the page, like with the help of js.-

Comment: Let me add example to my answer - sorry for not including answer, @Manish.